# Column count doesn't match value count at row 2

Tags: mysql

I am doing some sql exercises and I have encountered this error. I read some forum to find a solution and I understood what the problem is but I don't think that the number of columns and the number of data entered is wrong. Can someone help me? Thx.

```
CREATE TABLE volo (
idVolo INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
giornoSett VARCHAR (50),
cittàPart VARCHAR (50),
oraPart TIME,
cittàArr VARCHAR (50),
oraArr TIME,
tipoAereo VARCHAR (50),
FOREIGN KEY (cittàPart) REFERENCES aeroporto (città)
);


INSERT INTO volo (giornoSett, cittàPart, oraPart, cittàArr, oraArr, tipoAereo)
VALUES 
    ('martedi', 'Bristol', '16:00:00', 'Pescara', '18:00:00', 'Super 23'),
    ('martedi', 'Nantes' '08:00:00', 'Marsiglia', '11:00:00', 'Super 100'),
    ('mercoledi', 'Marsiglia', '09:00:00', 'Manchester', '10:00:00', 'Super Mx'),
    ('mercoledi', 'Palermo', '12:00:00', 'Roma', '18:00:00', 'Super Evo'),
    ('mercoledi', 'Bristol', '12:00:00', 'Nizza', '14:00:00', 'Tx Transporter'),
    ('giovedi', 'Manchester', '17:00:00', 'Parigi', '19:00:00', 'Tx Mega 2'),
    ('giovedi', 'Pescara', '24:00:00', 'Milano', '03:00:00', 'Tx Adv'),
    ('giovedi', 'Nizza', '10:00:00', 'Londra', '14:00:00', 'Tx One'),
    ('venerdi', 'Milano', '22:00:00', 'Bristol', '24:00:00', 'Tx One'),
    ('venerdi', 'Roma', '21:00:00', 'Palermo', '23:00:00', 'Tx One'),
    ('venerdi', 'Londra', '15:00:00', 'Nantes', '17:00:00', 'Tx One'),
    ('sabato', 'Liverpool', '21:00:00', 'Nantes', '22:00:00', 'Tx One'),
    ('sabato', 'Palermo', '16:00:00', 'Liverpool', '19:00:00', 'Tx One'),
    ('sabato', 'Londra', '19:00:00', 'Palermo', '22:00:00', 'Tx One'),
    ('domenica', 'Marsiglia', '20:00:00', 'Milano', '23:00:00', 'Tx One'),
    ('domenica', 'Roma', '21:00:00', 'Pescara', '23:00:00', 'Tx One'),
    ('domenica', 'Prigi', '06:00:00', 'Londra', '09:00:00', 'Tx One'),
    ('martedi', 'Londra', '23:00:00', 'Bristol', '03:00:00', 'Boing 463'),
    ('lunedi', 'Pescara', '22:00:00', 'Londra', '01:00:00', 'Boing 717'),
    ('lunedi', 'Nantes', '18:00:00', 'Londra', '20:00:00', 'Boing 12'),
    ('lunedi', 'Milano', '20:00:00', 'Palermo', '21:00:00', 'Boing 890');
```

Comment: Where is the error ? What error are you getting ? Can you please post the screenshot of the error ?

Comment: You're missing a comma here: `'Nantes' '08:00:00'`

Comment: You mention an error but haven't shared the error details. If you could add that to the end of the code you'll get a quicker response, as one of the commenters has suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing comma in second line after "Nantes". Plus, try using all lowercase column name separated by underscore. This is just a suggestion